# I Was Wondering How To Show A Matrix As a Matrix Map.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

so this is my first question on MathExchange, so I hope it's not dumb or obvious. But I was wondering how to show a function like $x^2 + 1$ as a matrix map of some value in the domain $X$ to the domain $Y$. I know the function is invertible because $x^2$ has the inverse function $\tfrac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ s.t. when multiplied together they give the value $1$. I was thinking maybe I'm choosing my basis wrong, currently trying to solve with $\{x^2, x, 1\}$. But if anyone has any ideas or resources that might answer this question, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: What are $X$ and $Y$? Are they the vector space of polynomials of degree at most two, $P_2[x]?$ Or are you considering the function $f(x)=x^2+1?$

Comment: I'm not sure, I exactly understand the question, but I'll try my best to explain. Since a function like $x^2 + 1$ is just a map from one domain to another, in this case $X$, and $Y$ are both the space $R$. As well that's I'm unsure of if the vector space is $P_2[x]$, as I don't know what vector space can have basis vectors that can represent both $x^2 + 1$ and $1/(x^2+1)$.